# Django Error "Boundfield has no attribute strip": Values being assigned to the form field objects themselves

Tags: python, django, forms

Apologies for asking a question that clearly has its roots in something very simple that I'm personally doing wrong, but I just can't find the bug here...

I've got a Django form called fixer_signup_form that feeds into a view called fixer_intro.

```
class fixer_signup_form(forms.Form):
    contact_first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=128, required=True)
    contact_last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=128, required=True)
    company_name = forms.CharField(max_length=256, label='Company Name (Optional)')
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
    password = forms.CharField(max_length=1024, widget=forms.PasswordInput, required=True)
    password2 = forms.CharField(max_length=1024, widget=forms.PasswordInput, required=True, label='Repeat Password')
    zip_code = forms.CharField(max_length=8, required=True)

    def clean(self):
            username = self.cleaned_data["email"]
            password = self.cleaned_data["password"]
            password2 = self.cleaned_data["password2"]
            zip_code = self.cleaned_data["zip_code"]

            if password != password2:
                    raise forms.ValidationError("Your passwords do not match. Please try again.")
            email_taken = User.objects.filter(username=username)
            if email_taken:
                    raise forms.ValidationError({'email':["There is already an existing account with that email address."]})
                    return self
            if password:
                    if len(password) < 9:
                            raise forms.ValidationError("Your password is too short. Please ensure that it is longer than 9 characters.")
            return self
```

Here

```
def fixer_intro(request):
    form = fixer_signup_form()
    if request.POST:
        form = fixer_signup_form(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data['email']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            company_name = form.cleaned_data['company_name']
            user = User.objects.create_user(username, username, password)
            login(request, user)
            fixer = fixer.create(user=user, company_name=company_name)
            fixer.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("Fixers:fixers_home"))
    return render(request, "public_fixer_intro.html",{'signup_form': form})
```

The form validates correctly. However, Django's debug throws up a "BoundField has no attribute 'strip'" error, and shows me that while the POST data has my received values inside of it, username and password values that I'm assigning within the view are getting assigned to the BoundField objects of the forms themselves, rather than the data they contain. For example:

```
username <django.forms.forms.BoundField object at 0x7fe9787a2410>
password <django.forms.forms.BoundField object at 0x7fe97873abd0>
```

So I'm clearly assigning my values improperly, but every resource I've seen online says that referencing the values of the form.cleaned_data[] dictionary is the proper way to get data from forms (rather than the POST request itself). Anyone able to tell me what I should be doing instead?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're returning `self` from `clean()` where you should be returning `self.cleaned_data`.

Although in fact, since Django 1.7. you [don't need to return anything](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/forms/validation/#validating-fields-with-clean) at all.

Comment: Aaaah! Yepp that was it. Thanks so much!